# graph is not being shown on the webpage

Tags: python, mongodb, d3.js

So here I am trying to build a dashboard using flask as my server, mongodb for database and have used dc.js, keen-dashboards.css and other basic requirements.

when I try to execute my app.py through console, no error occurs.
I then go to the browser and check for any graphs, no graph is shown, only the basic text in my index.html is printed. any reason why?

this small project was inspired by adil moujahid who built a dashboard using dc, d3, flask, mongodb.
As previous post was unclear due to lack of code snippets.
Here are a few:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/css/keen-dashboards.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/css/dc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/css/custom.css">

</head>

<body class="application">


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">CityCensus Dashboard</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">

                    <!--malepercity pie-->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="chart-wrapper">
                            <div class="chart-title">
                                Male population
                            </div>
                            <div class="chart-stage">
                                <div id="#malepercity-row-chart"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <p class="small text-muted">Built with &#9829; by <a href="https://keen.io">Keen IO</a></p>


    <script src="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/js/dc.js"></script>
    <script src="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/lib/js/queue.js"></script>

    <script src="C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/s`enter code here`tatic/lib/js/keen.min.js"></script>
    <script src='C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/dashboard/static/js/graphs.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**graph.js**

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "C:/mongodb/data/db/cities/census")
    .await(makeGraphs);

function makeGraphs(error, censusJson) {

    var citycensus = censusJson;
    censusJson.forEach(function (d) {
        d["population_male"]     = +d["population_male"];
        d["population_female"]   = +d["population_female"];
        d["literates_male"]      = +d["literates_male"];
        d["literates_female"]    = +d["literates_female"];
    })

    var ndx = crossfilter(citycensus);

    var namcity = ndx.dimensions(function (d) { return d["name_of_city"] });
    var namstat = ndx.dimensions(function(d) {return d["state_name"] });
    var popmale = ndx.dimensions(function (d) { return d["population_male"] });
    var popfemale = ndx.dimensions(function (d) { return d["population_female"] });
    var litmale = ndx.dimensions(function (d) { return d["literates_male"] });
    var litfemale = ndx.dimensions(function (d) { return d["literates_female"] });

    var all = ndx.groupAll();
    var percity = namcity.group();
    var malepercity = namstat.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d["population_male"] });
    var femalepercity = namstat.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d["population_female"] });
    var litmalepercity = namstat.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d["literates_male"] });
    var litfemalepercity = namstat.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d["literates_female"] });

    var maxmalepop = malepercity.top(1)[0].value;
    var maxfempop = femalepercity.top(1)[0].value;

    var malepercitychart = dc.rowChart("#malepercity-row-chart");

    malepercitychart
        .width(300)
        .height(250)
        .margins({ top: 25, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
        .dimension(namstat)
        .group(malepercity)
        .colors(d3.scale.category10())
        .elasticX(true)
        .XAxis().ticks(4);

   dc.renderAll();



};
```

**app.py**

```
 from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

import pymongo
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')                                              
client= pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)

MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'cities'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'census'
FIELDS = {'name_of_city': True, 'state_name': True , 'population_male': 
True, 'population_female': True, 'literates_male': True, 'literates_female': 
 True,'_id': False}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/cities/census")
def stats():
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    census = collection.find(projection=FIELDS)
    json_census = []
    for cen in census:
        json_census.append(cen)
    json_census = json.dumps(json_census, default=json_util.default)
    connection.close()
    return json_census

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your code and setup. Based on the information currently given it's impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @AntonvB sorry i suck at using stackoverflow, and i am a noob so attached the entire code. please help :(